# Make a web crawler in python to download pdf

Tags: python, pdf, web-crawler

I want to make a web crawler using Python and then download pdf file from that URL.
Can anyone help me? how to start?

Answer (score 2):

A good site to start is [ScraperWiki](https://scraperwiki.com/), a site where you can write and execute scrapers/crawlers online. Besides other languages it supports [Python](https://scraperwiki.com/docs/python/). It provides a lot of useful [tutorials](https://scraperwiki.com/docs/python/python_intro_tutorial/) and librarys for a fast start.